# Getting the content of a paragraph that has no class defined

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the content from a  paragraph full of text using Beautiful Soup, but I get everything tagged with the `<P>` tag. The content of a paragraph which I want to get has no class defined.

Here is the URL from which I want to extract the data: http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/turkeys-erdogan-to-be-sworn-in-as-president/2014/08/28/7461617c-2e7e-11e4-be9e-60cc44c01e7f_story.html.

Code which I tried is :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
target_url = "http://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/turkeys-erdogan-to-be-   sworn-in-as-president/2014/08/28/7461617c-2e7e-11e4-be9e-60cc44c01e7f_story.html"
data = urllib2.urlopen(target_url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
paragraphs = soup.find_all("p")
for p in paragraphs:
    print p
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what your problem actually is. :o

Comment: Which paragraph? Is there any chance of it changing? If not, then do you even need to use Python to grab it?

Comment: It's bound to be hard to describe the part you want to the computer if you cannot describe it to us.

Answer (score 3):

The site uses proper HTML5 tags, use

```
article = soup.find('article')
content = article.get_text()
```

Comment: @ kay : thanks for your help, yes it prints the content now, but the problem occurs when i have set of url's. "http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/09/world/europe/turkey-is-courted-by-us-to-help-fight-isis.html?module=Search&mabReward=relbias%3Aw%2C%7B%222%22%3A%22RI%3A18%22%7D&_r=0" which creates the errors, It gives me 302 and 303 error. here is the code that i have

Comment: 302 and 303 are redirects, not erros.

Comment: :yes, but i just want the page to be redirected to itself instead of some other links. please help me. url.txt is a text file having set of url's like the one before and the latest one..here is my code       import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text_file= open('url.txt', 'r')
for line in text_file:
 print line
 data = urllib2.urlopen(line).read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
 article = soup.find('article')
 content = article.get_text()
 print content
 saveFile = open('tmedia.txt','a')
 saveFile.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
 saveFile.write('\n')
 saveFile.close()

Comment: i am able to resolve redirection problem, by cookie enabler, but it gives the whole html page rather than only the text from the paragraph when I use get_text and it also says this "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"

Comment: I think you should open another question.